# Folder are file not zipping

Tags: java, android, zip

I have implemented Zip a folder or file then download and saving it to memory.
My problem is, it is downloading without any error but i am not getting Zip file, and if i click on downloaded file it is showing:

> Can't show

Or

> Can't display message.

My code:

```
String fileName = tvtitle.getText().toString();
        String fileExtension = tvtype.getText().toString();
        File imageDirectory = new File(Path);
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        String _path = Path;
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        File outputFile = new File(_path, fileName + fileExtension);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        File srcFile = new File(input.toString());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName()));
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        input.close();
        zos.close();
```

Comment: "I am not getting Zip file, and if i click on downloaded file" - if you're not getting a file, then how can you click on it?

Comment: use zip4j its easy and fast... http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

Comment: Sorry Zip file i am not getting, I am getting a file without zip and if i click on that file it is showing like that.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Can u guide me..? about zip4J any links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just don't know what is the type of this variable "**input**"

I think you should have FileInputStream (reading source file) to be paired with FileOutputStream (set to destination/zip file).

And this line of code:

```
File outputFile = new File(_path, fileName + fileExtension);
```

Your output must be .zip file right?
so, it should be:

```
File outputFile = new File(_path, fileName + ".zip");
```

or something similar

And it will be like this

```
String fileName = tvtitle.getText().toString();
String fileExtension = tvtype.getText().toString();
File imageDirectory = new File(Path);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageDirectory);
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
zos.closeEntry();
fis.close();
zos.close();
fos.close();
```

Comment: It is throwing FileNotFound Exception

Comment: In "input" i am passing the URL

Comment: How to pass URL to FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(url); is this correct way..?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/00000000000/Assets/Icons/FileFormats/pptx.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I think your error message is clear. It means your input file is not found. Are you sure you inputted the correct path or user that run your application has privilege to access that file?

Comment: What is "0000" means? I don't think it's the correct path? Or maybe "http:/" that missed one slash "/"?